# what is the maximum amount of characters a base64string can contain

Tags: c#

I have a regex to validate if the string is a base64 string. 
I also check if the mimimum legnth of the base 64 string is 4
but what is the maximum length of characters a base64 string can contain??

I created a regex and added a mimimun atribute and added validation.

```
public class EndpointAddRequest : RequestBase
{
    [MinLength(4, ErrorMessage = "The number of characters is less than the minimum amount")]
    [RegularExpression(RegexConstants.Base64String, ErrorMessage = "Invalid AccessDevice Uid")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "AccessDevice uid is required")]
 }
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13591616/what-is-the-maximum-length-of-base64-encoded-string-that-can-be-added-to-azure-q

Comment: There is no limit in base64 itself.

Comment: thnx i was already looking for it but couldn't find anything

Comment: @DulauMariusCristian That is specific to Azure and is not applicable here.

Comment: This depends on how the base64 is stored. If this is stored in a string, the maximum length is discussed in this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/140468/what-is-the-maximum-possible-length-of-a-net-string

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Base64 length calculation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13378815/base64-length-calculation)

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know there is no maximum length.

You can view the specification [here](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4648).

Answer (score 2):

There is no maximum. The minimum comes from the fact that Base64 encodes 3 input bytes into 4 on the output, plus padding if necesary. But there is no such limitation of how many characters can be encoded, as literally *any* byte stream (regardless or lenght) input is valid and will produce therefore an arbitrary long base64 output.

The practical limit is the amount of storage (either memory/disk/whatever) one has available, but the encoding itself doesn't place any restrictions.